# Issue setting Kivy to fullscreen

Tags: python, kivy, fullscreen, resolution

I'm trying to write an application that runs kivy at full screen. But these are my issues:

1) When I run the command:

```
#Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 1)
```

Then kivy appears to go full time, but the window has a lot of black spaces around the background image. Even if I elongate the image, kivy just cuts the image when showing it.

2) When I run this command to set the window size to the size of my screen:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1366')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '768')
```

This way actually gives me **a better result** than full screen, but kivy returns a height parameter of only 715 instead of the 768, which is the value I told kivy to use (as you can see in the Config.set() function above).

My screen resolution is 1366x768

How can I solve this issue and make my kivy app go real full screen?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did your issue get solved?

Comment: No. And I stopped working on the project

Answer (score 17):

Had a similar problem.  Using the 'auto' option got rid of the bands for me.

```
Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
```

Quote from Kivy Configuration Object documentation: "*If set to auto, your current display’s resolution will be used instead. This is most likely what you want.*"

Comment: this changes the resolution of the laptop to that of the app, i was hoping for the app to expand to the resolution of the laptop :(

Comment: The problem with 'auto' is that on some platforms it apparently does not detect the right screen size, so you have to also manually set it via Window.size = (w, h), as Joao Paulo mentioned in one of the answers, despite your having selected 'auto'. So when 'auto' fails to detect the right size, it just turns out to be a fancy alternative for True, with the same effect. I'm not sure if its the platform, or the window provider, but in any case I'm setting the size manually from now on to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = True
```

Do this before you `App.run()` method, and it should switch to fullscreen mode.

Cheers

Comment: for me at least, this doesn't solve the black around the edges issue. It does exactly the same as the Config.set method.

Comment: this answer solves the question, i dont get any 'black' spaces

Comment: just a question, will this work on fullscreen android apps aswell?

Comment: I removed your full stop because it works, however feel free to put it back.  Thanks this was really useful

Comment: This may be b/c I'm running linux, but when I did this my screen started freaking out - changing between a black screen and the background every half-second.

Comment: This doesn't solve the "black-around-the-edges" issue for me, either. I'm on a Windows PC with a 3440x1440p screen.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to do it as follows:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.maximize()
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most effective solution. The other solutions either didn't work, or were very slow on my otherwise fast gaming PC (Windows 10 with 3440x1440p screen)

Comment: This solution works fine in maximizing the window, but when the application is minimized and user tries to open the app again, the application doesn't show up. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: It is not full screen solution

Answer (score 6):

I just want to complement:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (1366, 768)
Window.fullscreen = True
```

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering lately For those who are still struggling to figure out how to have the true fullscreen. I have managed to get the rid of those black strip by adding  `Config.set('graphics','window_state'_'maximized'` just after the fullscreen call. the whole code looks like

```py
from kivy.config import Config

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
    Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
    Config.write()
    YourApp().run()
```

Comment: Config is located at `from kivy.config import Config`

Answer (score 0):

This will work no matter what is your resolution.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = True
Window.maximize()
```