# How to boot android directly into my application in full screen

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, face-recognition

Heres my working KIVY app for face detection :-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import cv2
import numpy as np
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
#FACE_CLASSIFIER = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):

        #faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        count = 0
        while (count < 40):
            
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()
            print (np.shape(frame))
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            #gray = frame
            faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
            
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            count = count + 1
        
        video_capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return Label(text = "Face Detection Application")
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

1. Is it possible to always have this app running in full screen mode
   all the time, even after device restart ?
2. Also how to disable user
   touch/home/back buttons with this app running ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lock Task Mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) of [Dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) and various [KIOSK applications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fullykiosk.singleapp&hl=en) or [Custom Launchers](https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/).
Also take a look at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891217/issue-setting-kivy-to-fullscreen).